# Handle List Values through JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, fasterxml

I have below format generated through my JAXB Marshaller :

```
<cell column="0">
        <content>Address Information</content>
    </cell>
```

But I am expecting the output as

```
<cell>Address Information</cell>
```

How can I do this.

Comment: Providing some code would greatly increase the chance of getting someone to answer.

Comment: Use the `@XmlValue` annotation.

Comment: Voting to close for "no code" reason.

Comment: And, by the way, what has [tag:fasterxml] to do with the question?

Comment: @XmlValue solves my issue. Thanks!